# Date and DateTime handling - A particular scenario fails

Tags: java, date, junit

I will have to write test cases to check the working of some queries say,which retrieves records with date **today**, **next_week, previous_year** and the like.

Its a junit test case basically, which I am implementing by:

> 1.Inserting records with date corresponding to TODAY,NEXT_WEEK,PREVIOUS_YEAR
>
> 2.So, I will know for a particular query, what are the records to be returned, I will execute the query, retrieve the records for a particular condition and check it for the correct records.

In this procedure, while executing TODAY's case, I am facing a problem.

If I run my test case by the midnight, say 11.59, first insertion of data will happen, which will insert a date,say 24-4-2012T11:59:00.00

And before the execution of the query, the date becomes tomorrow, that is 25-4-2012T00:00:00.00

The TODAY condition will execute the query with 25th not 24th. So my testcase fails.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I resolve this problem ?

Write more testable code :)

My guess is that you're taking "the current date" using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, `Calendar.getInstance()` or something similar. That code can't easily be intercepted to give you "whatever value you want". Instead, introduce a `Clock` interface with a single method (`now()` or something similar) returning whatever representation of "now" you want to use. (Personally I'd use `Instant` from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) but it's up to you.)

Now inject a `Clock` into the code you want to test, e.g. as a parameter constructor. For tests, use a stub implementation which returns whatever you want it to. For production, use a "real" implementation.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet. Do I understand it correctly, I have to return a now() value from my own Clock, which will be inserted into the DB and then used in the query for retrieval ?

Comment: @Sowmiya: Whether you use it for insertion is a different matter (we don't know what the data represents) - but you would at least use it for querying, so that you know what "today" means.

Comment: Here, my retrieval procedure is like, I will be firing a service GetRecordsForToday, where I cannot specify any date,but the service takes care of manipulating the date Today in the backend. [I am testing the working of the **insertion using one service** and **retrieval using another service-whose today is always today** :( ]

Comment: @Sowmiya: So you should decide on some date, insert a record for that date, set your fake clock to be on the same date, and test that you retrieve the record. Then do another test where the clock is set to a *different* date, and check that you *don't* get the record. Also consider time zones :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you use `new Date()` for the notion of today. You should **preserve** the date for comparison; I believe this is the root of the issue, you need to preserve expected values before and after query execution to be testable/verifiable:

```
Date today = new Date();

// update the data layer using today

Date recordedDate = // fetch the date that is recorded

assertEquals(today, recordedDate);
```

Presumably, you'll use some other facility such as `java.util.Calendar` to calculate the time points mentioned in your question.

Comment: But this solution has the same problem as the original - the date may change between the two calls to `new Date()`.

Comment: There is only _one_ call to `new Date()` to preseve it in `today`; that's how I wanted the code to sound like.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But basically,I will store the date at midnight and preserve it..  I need to query[which will happen tomorrow's first minute] from the DB the date value for today and check with the preserved date. So, in this case it will fail right? :)

Comment: Is this really a unit test with JUnit? It sounds like you're store "now" in one place and the check it in another place; so in this case, yes it always fails and I believe the answer from @JonSkeet is a better choice for you.

Comment: @nobeh Actually, the functionality is like, the user will enter values in a form. And using a service,say getData, we will read values. Now, my case has to check both. 1. Insertion works well. 2.Retrieval returns the perfect data. I know what values I insert. So based on that, I will be expecting an output. Everytime, it works fine, except for the case I described.